# Error when idexing document in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I get this error from elastc:

```
failed to parse date field [2020-12-30T23:00:00Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ] CausedBy: Type: date_time_parse_exception Reason: Text '2020-12-30T23:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Works on my machine but not when I deploy to customer system

To me the format and the value look like they should match.
In the mapping I define the format:

```
.Date(s => s.Name(n => n.AsDate).Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it thinks `Z` is a formatter. Wrap it in single quotes like you did the `T`.

```
.Date(s => s.Name(n => n.AsDate).Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
```